# Porque la expresión regular NO FUNCIONA?

Tags: php, regex

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario y validarlo con PHP y me estoy topando con el problema de las **expresiones regulares**. No se si no funcionan o estoy viendo documentación desactualizada porque me saltan los siguientes errores. Primero tengo el formulario así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando lo envio siempre me tira el error de que de **algún modo** la condición no se cumple (Y se que esta en la **expresión regular --      "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]$/"     --  porque me viene pasando lo mismo con Javascrypt**. Sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque cumplo con la condición me marca el error (El error Lo hice aparecer en amarillo con estilos CSS) mi codigo es este:

```
    <?php

function validateUsername($name)
{
    // Longitud mininma 
    if (strlen($name) < 3) {
        return false;
    }
    // Caracteres de "A" a la "Z" 
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $name)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Fue correcto
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function validatePassword1($password1)
{
    // Longitud mininma 
    if (strlen($password1) < 4) {
        return false;
    }
    // Caracteres de "A" a la "Z" 
    else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]$/", $password1)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Fue correcto
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function validatePassword2($password1, $password2)
{
    // No coinciden
    if ($password1 != $password2) {
        return false;
    }
    // Fue correcto
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function validateEmail($email)
{
    // Longitud mininma 
    if (strlen($email) == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // Si algo esta escrito pero sin caracteres correctos 
    else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Fue correcto
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function validateEmail2($email, $email2)
{
    // No coinciden
    if ($email != $email2) {
        return false;
    }
    // Fue correcto
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

//Validación de datos enviados

if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
} else {
    $user = "";
}
$userValue = "";

if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
} else {
    $pass = "";
}
$passValue = "";

if (isset($_POST['pass2'])) {
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
} else {
    $pass2 = "";
}
$pass2Value = "";

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    $email = "";
}
$emailValue = "";

if (isset($_POST['email2'])) {
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
} else {
    $email2 = "";
}
$email2Value = "";

$ok = 0;




if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (!validateUsername($_POST['user'])) {
        $user = "error";
    }
    if (!validatePassword1($_POST['pass'])) {
        $pass = "error";
    }
    if (!validatePassword2($_POST['pass2'], $_POST['pass2'])) {
        $pass2 = "error";
    }

    if (!validateEmail($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = "error";
    }

    if (!validateEmail2($_POST['email'], $_POST['email2'])) {
        $email2 = "error";
    }


    // Guardo los valores para no tener que reescribir
    $userValue = $_POST['user'];
    $emailValue = $_POST['email'];

    // Comprobar que todo va bien

    if ($user != 'error' && $pass != 'error' && $pass2 != 'error' && $email != 'error') {
        $status = 1;
    }
} else {
    $ok = "<p>Formulario enviado con exito</p>";
}

?>







<div class="bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12">

    <p class="registrarse">Registrarse</p>
    <form method="post" id="form_registrarse">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="username" class="  col-5 float-left"><strong>Nombre: </strong> <small id='' class='<?= $user ?> form-text text-muted'>Minimo 3 caracteres</small></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" name="user" id="user" value='<?= $userValue ?>'>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="  col-5 float-left"><strong>Contraseña:</strong> <small id='' class='<?= $pass ?> form-text text-muted'>8 caracteres minimo</small></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" name='pass' id="pass" value=''>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="  col-5 float-left"><strong>Confirmar contraseña:</strong> <small id='' class='<?= $pass2 ?> form-text text-muted'>Repite contraseña</small></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" name='pass2' id="pass2" value=''>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="  col-5 float-left"><strong>email:</strong><small id='' class='<?= $email ?> form-text text-muted'>Coloca tu email</small></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" autocomplete="off" name='email' value='<?= $emailValue ?>'>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="etiquetas_crear_cuenta  col-5 float-left"><strong>Confirmar email:</strong><small id='' class='<?= $email2 ?> form-text text-muted'>Repite el mismo email</small></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" autocomplete="off" name='email2' value=''>
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name='enviar' id="enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <p id="mensajeError"></p>

    <div class="bg-light border">

        <div class="col-3 " id="Cropbox_megusta">
            <img src="/Imagenes/Crop-1.png" width="80px" height="80px"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="col-9 " id="Parrafocondiciones">Al usar y crear una cuenta en <strong>CropBox.net</strong> aceptas
                los terminos y condiciones</br> del website</p>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Es como si esta expresion **"/^[0-9a-zA-Z]$/"** no me funcionara ¿Es correcta? **(De pronto marca, luego no, recargas y luego si y luego también etc...)**

Answer (score 2):

La expresión `/^[a-zA-Z]$/` indica si la cadena comienza con `[a-zA-Z]` y termina con `[a-zA-Z]` pero lo estás condicionado a que sea solo un carácter.

Puedes Checar en el primer ejemplo que la expresión no es válida para `Jose` pero sí para `P`

```js
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]$/g;

const texts =  [
  "Jose",
  "P",
  "ho5la"
];

for (text of texts) {
  const isValid = text.match(regex) == null ? 'invalida' : 'valida';
  console.log('La cadena ' + text + ' es ' + isValid);
}
```

Tu expresión regular nunca funciona en tu código porque como se menciono `/^[a-zA-Z]$/` solo sirve para un carácter, pero tú antes validas que la longitud mínima sea de 3, entonces no va a funcionar, dado que esa condición solo funciona si los caracteres son 3 o más, y la expresión regular solo hace match si es un caracter.

**Solucion**

Simplemente agrega `+` al final de tu grupo, quedando `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`. El `+` indica que puede coincidir en 1 o más caracteres.

Puedes probar que con esa expresión regular funciona tanto para `Jose` como para `P` y falla para `ho5la` lo cual es esperado.

```js
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/g;

const texts =  [
  "Jose",
  "P",
  "Ho5la"
];

for (text of texts) {
  const isValid = text.match(regex) == null ? 'invalida' : 'valida';
  console.log('La cadena ' + text + ' es ' + isValid);
}
```

**Mejora**

Puedes validar la longitud y que sea solo `[a-zA-Z]`, con una sola expresión regular. Agregando `{3,}` en lugar de `+`. Esto indica que debe ser 3 o más caracteres. `/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/`

Puedes Checarque la expresión es válida para `Jose` pero no lo es para `P`, ya que no cumple el mínimo de longitud.

```js
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/g;

const texts =  [
  "Jose",
  "P",
  "ho5la"
];

for (text of texts) {
  const isValid = text.match(regex) == null ? 'invalida' : 'valida';
  console.log('La cadena ' + text + ' es ' + isValid);
}
```

Por lo que tu función de PHP podría quedar simplemente como

```
function validateUsername($name)
{
    return (bool) (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/", $name))
}
```